# How to hide menu only on Home page wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes, customization

I m using a one page theme. I would like to disable or choose not to show the menu on the home page. But when user scrolls down to the next page the menu should become fixed. I have removed the menu from the home page now, however i'm not able to get the menu to be fixed on top for the other pages.

Please advice.

Answer (score 5):

You can also go the `CSS` way.

WordPress adds a class `home` to the body attribute in home page. You can target that particular attribute to hide the menu as shown below.

```
.home .menu-class-name{
    display:none;
}
```

This will hide the menu from home page but will show it on other pages

Note - replace `.menu-class-name` with your own menu class

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I m using theme Barrci. Its an one page theme and i need to disable the menu only for the home or the intro section

Answer (score 0):

you can do it some thing like the below code:

```
<?php
if(is_front_page())
{

//Just comment out the menu section
}
else
{
//write your code to show the menu section
}
?>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I m using theme Barrci. Its an one page theme and i need to disable the menu only for the home or the intro section