# PHP - Hide Element Only On Home Page - WordPress Site

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my `footer.php` file, I have this bit of code towards the end of the file:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?> 

<div class="website-by">
<br>
Website by <a href="https://gatewaywebdesign.com/" target="blank">Gateway Web Design</a>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

As you can see, I've created a "website by" link, which links to another website when clicked on.

But I don't want this text, or the div that contains it, to appear at all on the home page of the site:

https://thehamburgercollection.com/

I've checked other stackoverflow articles that suggest doing so with [JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705970/hide-div-on-specific-url-with-css-or-js), which I've added to my `scripts.js` file:

```
//hide link on the home page
document.ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('https://thehamburgercollection.com/')) {
      //Hide the element.
      jQuery('.website-by').hide();
    }
  });
```

And I've also tried hiding the div on the home page with CSS that was [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524782/how-to-hide-menu-only-on-home-page-wordpress):

```
.home .website-by {
    display: none;
}
```

But unfortunately neither of these methods have worked. I've declared my class as `website-by` in the `footer.php` file, and have added the JQuery that should target that class in the `scripts.js` file, and have also added the suggested CSS. Any idea why either the JQuery or CSS code isn't working?

This is a WordPress website and a custom there. Any help / suggestions / education is appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/ Don't hide it with jQuery, just don't put it on the page if its the front page in the first place.

Comment: Agree that doing it in PHP makes more sense, but just for future reference the CSS didn't work because your theme isn't adding the customary classes to the `body` tag (though actually just a `.website-by` selector would probably have worked), and the jQuery indexOf doesn't work because it redirects to the site url without the trailing `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a WordPress guru, but have you tried doing an `if` condition in the `footer.php`? if I got your question right, you need the `.website-by` to not appear elsewhere but the home page. Maybe something like

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?> 

<?php if (!is_home()): ?>
    <div class="website-by">
    <br>
    Website by <a href="https://gatewaywebdesign.com/" target="blank">Gateway Web Design</a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: To appear everywhere but the homepage, correct. Thank you for your answer - I didn't think about just doing it with PHP. This worked!